# why restart the service

Tags: android, android-service, bindservice

i have a problem in my service, the service is runnig from MainActivity (i am doing test) and extends of service.

i want to use the service from foreground and background (when the app is closed) and i already have my first problem:

my service(have a counter that is displayed by LOG)  is restarting when i close the app.

also i want to be able to use the service with the open app and close app, in other words to use both the Service Started and Link Service

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private Thread backgroundThread;
private boolean isRunning;

public MyService() {
    Log.e("MyService","constructor");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    isRunning = false;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e("onStartCommand","Servicio Llamado");

    if (!this.isRunning) {
        Log.e("onStartCommand","hilo iniciandose");
        this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
        runTask();
    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("onDestroy","servicio destuido");
}

private void runTask(){
    this.isRunning = true;
    this.backgroundThread.start();
}
private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.e("myTask","hilo iniciado");
        int i = 0;
        do{
            pauseService();

            Log.e("myTask","hilo contador: "+i);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CONTADOR = "+j, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //no working :(
            i++;
        }while (i<10);

        /*
        //linea de detencion del servicio
        //stopSelf();

        isRunning=false;

        backgroundThread.interrupt();

        //backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
        */
        Log.e("myTask","hilo cerrado");
    }
};
private void pauseService(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

In main Activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
 intent.putExtra("iteraciones",10);
 startService(intent);
```

why because the service restarts when I close the application and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Create a foreground service. You can check the official documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Hi, i can't...  I could or can bind the service from Activity but i want to combine the 2 service type :  link service and service started.

But, that is not the main question.

My question is, why because the service restarts when I close the application and how can I avoid it?